# "error: Package `color-theme-' is unavailable"during emacs startup

Tags: emacs

I'm a newbie of emacs and I followed the guide from [this web](https://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d)
step by step.

But when it startup, it said

- Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/mrfive/.emacs.d/init.el':
- error: Package `color-theme-' is unavailable
- To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
  cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
  the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

what should I do now?
Thank?

Comment: the information with "--debug-init" is :
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (gnutls-error #<process melpa.org> -54)
  signal(gnutls-error (#<process melpa.org> -54))
  gnutls-negotiate(:process #<process melpa.org> :type gnutls-x509pki :hostname "melpa.org")
  open-gnutls-stream("melpa.org" #<buffer  *url-http-temp*> "melpa.org" 443)
  network-stream-open-tls("melpa.org" #<buffer  *url-http-temp*> "melpa.org" 443 (:type tls :nowait t))
  open-network-stream("melpa.org" #<buffer  *url-http-temp*> "melpa.org" 443 :type tls :nowait t)
  byte-code("\306\211\n\307>\203$

Comment: Oh, I try it again today, the error don't occur again confusingly.Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by running emacs with the --debug-init switch i.e.

```
emacs --debug-init
```

This will give you more meaningful information which will help track down the problem. If the additional information doesn't help, add it to your question above and  that will help others narrow down where the issue could be.

Comment: the error doesn't reappear, but thank you for your attention